# Creating time lapse video from ffmpeg with jpg images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4

I am trying to creating time lapse video.
I have images file named `IM_date_time.jpg` as in `IMG_20210516_235523.jpg` (2048 × 1536)
I have around 3700 files.
I have used this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i IMG*.jpg -r 5 -s hd1080 output.mp4
```

This is not working, and I don't understand why it want to write to my images. The `-y` should not be needed.

I what to get a video in hd (full hd or just hd) and one images to represent 1 or 2 frames per sec.

I am using Linux Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS and ffmpeg 4.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You may have overwritten your images

The glob wildcard (`*`) expands and your command gets interpreted as:

```
ffmpeg -y -i IMG_20210516_235523.jpg IMG_20210516_235524.jpg IMG_20210516_235525.jpg ... -r 5 -s hd1080 output.mp4
```

Combined with `-y` (overwrite without asking) this means that all but the first image were considered to be outputs and have been overwritten. So all of the following images are now re-encoded copies of the first image.

## Use `-pattern_type glob`

On Linux and macOS you can the [image muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) input option `-pattern_type glob`. This will allow you to use `IMG*.jpg` and behave as expected.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -pattern_type glob -i 'IMG*.jpg' -vf "scale=-2:1080,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Frame rate is set with the `-framerate` image muxer input option. Default of `-framerate 25` is applied if `-framerate` is omitted.
- Some players don't like low frame rates. Add the output option `-r 10` if you notice problems. It will duplicate frames to go from 5 to 10, but the output video will look the same.

Comment: Thanks, it works out of the box.
That is great. The images (4721) works as a charm, looks nice.